# How to assign self to another class object, while navigating to another view controller with out segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uistoryboardsegue

I am using below code to navigate to another view controller, i want to assign this self to a delegate of another class, how do i do it ?

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];

self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: just add one navigation controller in storyboard with edit => embed In =>Navigation controller . and just write your code your navigation work perfectly .

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get your view Controller from Navigation Controller**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationControllerID"];

TargetVC *targetVC = (TargetVC *)controller.viewControllers.firstObject
   //OR
TargetVC *targetVC = (TargetVC *)controller.topViewController;

targetVC.mydelegate = self;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Get your view Controller from TabBar Controller**

```
   UITabBarController *homeTabBar=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeTabBarID"];

   TargetVC *targetVC =nil;

   UINavigationController *nav = [homeTabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

  //if you have multiple tab then you can give Index as per your ViewController
   targetVC =(TargetVC*)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

   targetVC.mydelegate = self;

   [self.navigationController presentViewController:homeTabBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: target view controller is a tab bar and the particular index is zero, i have to do is secondVC.mydelegate = self;

Comment: then you can set your Storyboard id to your view controller and get from your storyboard id i have updated my answer

Comment: your issue is fixed?

Comment: can you add the Serene Shot of storyboard?

Comment: every controller in storyboard has a navigation controller , you meant to add the storyboardID for navigation controlller of that particular controller right ?

Comment: In your case which controller  you need to pass  delegate give me those controller name.

Comment: from a simple view controller to another view controller (which is inside a tabbar controller and embedded in a navigation controller)

Comment: then you need to find by using storyboard Identifier, first tabbar controller -> navigationVC -> yourViewControllr

Comment: Sir if you edit your answer with the information i added in my answer, (with some more info)
it may help some one.
i would love to accept your answer.
thanks for your time.

Comment: can you add storyboard  Screen Shot so i can update perfectly

Comment: i am really sorry but that violates my companies rules and regulations.
but have you tested my answers, it works for me.
if you update it i will remove my answer & accept yours.
Thanks